# Stuck with a multi-part MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with a MySQL query. I have tried a lot of ways but no luck so far. I'm still trying but I need a tip to follow the right path. The query is to get data from 3 tables based on some conditions. All is going well, just give me a hint on this part of the query.

```
select id,userid,amount from coins where id in (3,4)
```

This gives me:

```
id | userid | amount
3  |   2    |   900
4  |   3    |  1100
```

I want to get the record that has the maximum amount, ie here 1100, but I want to keep the  where condition at the end (3,4), as it is the nested part, coming from another query (another table). So basically I need a solution that is in the same query.

If my question is not clear, please let me know, I will add the whole query and all tables data. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dda, i am surprised programmers care of writing 'i' instead of 'I' and suck mistakes. By the way thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick;

```
select id,userid,amount from coins where id in (3,4) order by amount DESC limit 1
```

Comment: That's going to return the 900 record, unless you specify the order direction (ie descending)

Comment: Add desc to the order by, else you'll get the lowest number.

Comment: yo man, trick worked for me. I wasn't sure it will work for me in so many joins but done. Thanks